# Cannot use equal operator between two arrays in a class mimicking how ArrayList works

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So as an exercise, I created this class "Array" to mimic how a normal ArrayList would work with some additional functions that I wanted.

I am having an issue for a method called "intersect".
In this method, what is suppose to happen is that it takes two entered Array (from the array class I created) objects and compares the values in them. If there are common numbers between the two arrays, it creates a new array and puts them in this new array. This way, I can print the values in this new array.

I however can't use the equal operator here because I need the normal Java Array type and not the class I made for the argument "Array secondArray" that I have used.
Due to this, I can use the If statement like this:
if (array[i] == secondArray[j])

How can I work around this?

Here is the **main class**:

```
package com.company;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Array array = new Array(3);
    Array array1 = new Array(3);

    array.insert(1);
    array.insert(2);
    array.insert(3);

    array1.insert(2);
    array1.insert(3);
    array1.insert(4);

    array.print();
}
```

}

Here is the **Array class** I made:

```
public class Array {
 int length;
 Integer[] array;

public Array(int length) {
    array = new Integer[this.length=length];
}

public void insert(int item) {

    if (array[length - 1] == null) { //if there is no value in the last index
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == null) {
                array[i] = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (array[length - 1] != null) { //if there is a value in the last index
        int newLength = this.length + 1;
        Integer[] newArray = new Integer[newLength];

        for (int j = 0; j < newLength; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    newArray[j] = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        newArray[newLength - 1] = item;
        this.array = newArray;
        this.length = newLength;
    }
}

public int intersect(Array secondArray) {
    //Store array1 and array2
    //Go through all of the values in each array
    //If the values are equal, store them in another array
    Integer[] commonValues = new Integer[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == secondArray[j]) {

            }
        }
    }
    return commonValues[0];
}
```

}

Comment: Your `insert` method is odd. Because you only increase the length by 1 each time, you will always be hitting the second branch after you first hit it. And there's no need for the nested loop: just remove the outer loop; or make it even easier, and use `this.array = Arrays.copyOfRange(this.array, newLength)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AndyTurner! I need to go over the intersect method again but  my goal here is to do it without using any of the Arrays methods.

Answer (score 1):

> I however can't use the equal operator here because I need the normal
>   Java Array type and not the class I made for the argument "Array
>   secondArray" that I have used. Due to this, I can use the If statement
>   like this: if (array[i] == secondArray[j])

Since java does not support [custom indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) that would allow you to write `myCustomArray[i] == myCustomArray2[i]`, you will need to use method for getting elements. Do something like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) does: `myCustomArray.get(i) == myCustomArray2.get(i)`.

Comment: This is what I thought as well but thought maybe there might an easier way or something that I don't understand. Okay then I guess I will have to try this.
And wow, that's very convenient of C# to have custom indexers(first time I'm hearing this word)!